# How to get JSON key/value pairs instead an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I need to retrieve some data from a Google Spreadsheet via App Script for which I set up a DoGet function. Currently I´m retrieving an array but a I need data comes as JSON key-value pairs format.

The table on Google Sheets looks like this:

[image: description]

the DoGet function is set up like this:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); 

  var returnData = sheet.getRange('A1:B2').getValues()

return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(returnData))
}
```

I´m retriving this:

```
[
    ["fruit", "vegetable"],
    ["ABC", "DEF"]
]
```

I need to retrieve JSON key:value pairs like this:

```
{
"fruit": "ABC",
"vegetable": "DEF"
}
```

Comment: `Object.fromEntries` - oh, no, wait you'd have to rotate that matrix

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are extracting a value from a Google Sheet, so this response is how your data is represented on your sheet.

```json
[
    ["fruit", "vegetable"],
    ["ABC", "DEF"]
]
```

You can obviously map your data in order to get the response that you want.

```js
const arrayData = [
    ["fruit", "vegetable"],
    ["ABC", "DEF"]
];

const resultObject = arrayData[0].reduce((acc, key, index) => {
    acc[key] = arrayData[1][index];
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(resultObject);
```

but this comes with a problem, what if you have more rows, how would you handle it then?

Answer (score 0):

**You can leverage on `Array:slice` and `Array:map` functions in and accomplish your expected output.**

**Refer the below code :**

```js
const nestedArray = [
  ["fruit", "vegetable"],
  ["ABC", "DEF"],
  ["CC", "DDD"],
  ["FF", "GG"],
  ["FF2", "G3G"]
];

function arrTranformer(arr) {
  let transformedArray = arr.slice(1).map(innerArray => {
    let obj = {};
    if (innerArray.length >= 2) {
      obj[arr[0][0]] = innerArray[0];
      obj[arr[0][1]] = innerArray[1];
    }
    return obj;
  });

  return transformedArray;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrTranformer(nestedArray)));
```